# Unable to play mp4 video in ios6 ipad by MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, ios6, cocos2d-iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mp4

I have developed a universal application in Cocos2D. I am using the same code for iPhone and iPad.

The problem is that I am playing video by CCVideoPlayer. CCVideoPlayer is a extension class. For iphone I am using mov file and for ipad I am using mp4 file. But mp4 file is not playing. I did not change the code and when I tried to play the same video which I am using for iPhone it is working on the iPad also. So I think that problem is with mp4 video not with my code. So any help will be appreciated to solve my problem.

```
-(void)playMovie{
   [CCVideoPlayer playMovieWithFile:@"video_ipad.mp4"];
}
```

Comment: how is the MP4 encoded? iOS does not support all formats. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW20

You have to encode the video with a supported format.